# CSS: can change height by px, but not by %

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to edit the CSS of my Wordpress theme.

I have an element whose height I can successfully change from within Element Inspector, if I specify a certain pixel height, for example:

```
height=100px;
```

But when I try to change the height by specifying a percentage, for example:

```
height=50%;
```

The element does not change height. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong, or how to troubleshoot?

None of the parent elements appear to have any height properties.

Comment: Could you give us a piece of code from your CSS file? So we can give you some advice

Comment: Percentages are based off of the "closest relative parent" AFAIK (and I suspect it does not have a height applied) - the *actual* issue will become clear with relevant (and minimal) context to recreate the observed effect. Troubleshooting: live CSS editing in Developer Tools ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### http://jsfiddle.net/cMYdw/

The reason you are unable to change `height` % is because you need to set a `100% height` on your parent element, in this case your `body`.

Now, it doesn't necessarily have to be the `body`, it can be any **parent element**, but I've used `body` in my example to get the idea across. For example, have a look below.

```
html, body { height: 100%;   } 
div { height: 100%;  background: #F52887; }
```

Comment: `html, body{
  height:100%;
}` is the key. If it's an elements first children of `body`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my answer per se. I did say that.

Comment: How do you know the parent is `body`?

Comment: I am trying to help the OP understand the concept, that's all.

Comment: @AliGajani ok, but than just say that a parent element *needs* a defined height in order to apply `%` to the children.

Comment: Weird, I never made a guess. I am quite certain. Read my answer again.

Comment: Why you use `100%` width for a DIV? By default it's already "100%" (**auto**)  ;)

Comment: OK here is my site, http://www.panyadee.ac.th/test/ and here is my code:


'.section-inner {
height:115px;
}'

'.blog-info {
background-image:url('http://www.panyadee.ac.th/test/wp-content/themes/hemingway-child/banner-panyadee-1280w-forweb.jpg');
background-size:contain;
width: 55%;
height: 100%;
}'


My end result is to have the middle banner image scale (without tiling or truncating) with browser size.  I can get the width to change without issue (I think).  And I think that is because the immediate parent element has a 'width' set.  But none of the parent elements have a 'height' set.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting.  I have no idea how to format when leaving a comment.  Can I add an extra line?  How do I format lines of code?  Putting a single quote around the text does not seem to do anything.

Comment: We can't access your site. Admin access only.

Comment: Whoops. Hold...  Try now.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

Length values defined in percentage(%) gets value based on the value of containing box. Set the height of parent box to any absolute values (like height: 500px).

### Long Answer

The default value of length properties(height,width) have default value `auto`, we should know how these values works(in block display):

- `auto`: `Width` is set in such a way that the block's overall width(including border,padding,margin) occupies the parent block's width.

  However, `Height` is always set according the calculated height of child elements (including border,padding,margin).
- `percentage(%): The length properties gets value according to that of the containing box.

The elements like body and div fill up the available width while having only the height required for the available content.

**Before**

```
<body>
<div style="height: 100%"> <!-- This have same affect as "height: auto" -->
Hello World!
</div>
</body>
```

**After**

```
<body>
<div style="height: 500px;">
<div style="height: 100%;"> <!-- sets the height of div equal to 500px -->
Hello World!
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks all--very helpful.  I'll try to track down (or set) a parent height.